# How to plot a time series graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, plotly, seaborn

I have a time series data as follows:

```
Datum   Menge
1/1/2018 0:00   19.5
1/1/2018 0:15   19.0
1/1/2018 0:30   19.5
1/1/2018 0:45   19.5
1/1/2018 1:00   21.0
1/1/2018 1:15   19.5
1/1/2018 1:30   20.0
1/1/2018 1:45   23.0
```

and the dataframe `data` has a shape of (14880, 2). In the `Menge` column, there are only 11807 values available and the rest are `nan`

I am trying to plot it as follows:

```
data.plot()
plt.show()
```

and this gives me

[image: Graph]

But I want to plot the same using `seaborn` or `plotly`

for `seaborn` I have tried:

```
x = data.Datum
y = data.Menge.values
sns.lineplot(x = x, y = y, data = data)
```

and it gives me the output as:

```
Out[3]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x21286bb8668>
```

and a new graph window is opened but it says `Figure 1 (Not Responding)`

So, I have 2 questions:

1. In the above graph, we can see the x-axis has index, but I would like it to be the `Datum` values there. How can it be changed?
2. I would like to achieve this in seaborn or plotly, so is there a way to achieve all this in either?

Comment: Hmm, doing it your way and by doing the typical `sns.lineplot(x = 'Datum', y = 'Menge', data = data)` works for me. What are the datatypes of the columns?

Comment: @HS-nebula `Out[3]: 
Datum     object
Menge    float64
dtype: object`

Comment: How are you running your code?

Comment: Also look into using `cufflinks` to work with plotly

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Considering a toy dataframe:

- **seaborn solution**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({"Datum": ['1/1/2018 0:00',
                             '1/1/2018 0:15',
                             '1/1/2018 0:30',
                             '1/1/2018 0:45',
                             '1/1/2018 1:00',
                             '1/1/2018 1:15',
                             '1/1/2018 1:30',
                             '1/1/2018 1:45 '],
                   "Menge": [19.5, 19.,19.5,19.5,21,19.5,20,23]})
sns.lineplot(x="Datum", y="Menge", data=df)
plt.xticks(rotation=15)
plt.title('seaborn-matplotlib example')
plt.show()
```

[image]

- **plotly solution**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

trace1 = go.Scatter(x=df.Datum,
                    y=df.Menge,
                    name = "plotly example",
                    line = dict(color = 'blue'),
                    opacity = 0.4)

layout = dict(title='plotly example',)

fig = dict(data=[trace1], layout=layout)
iplot(fig)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, I tried your suggestion with `Plotly`, It runs without error, but it gives no graph as output in spyder, but gives the output in Jupyter. Any idea why is it so?

Comment: You can modify last line of code as `plot(fig)` and you get an html page.

Answer (score 18):

The cleanest setups, even for multiple time series, are:

- plotly:  `px.line()`
- seaborn: `lineplot()`

---

**plotly:**

```
px.line(df, x = df.index, y = df.columns)
```

[image]

---

**Seaborn:**

```
sns.lineplot(data = df)
```

[image]

---

**Complete code for both seaborn and plotly:**

The following code sample will let you produce both plots.

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from datetime import datetime
import plotly.express as px
import matplotlib as mpl
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# sample data in a pandas dataframe

np.random.seed(23)
observations = 75
df=pd.DataFrame(dict(A=np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1.1, size=observations).tolist(),
                    B=np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1.1, size=observations).tolist(),
                    C=np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1.1, size=observations).tolist(),
                    ))
df.iloc[0,] = 0
df = df.cumsum()

firstdate = datetime(2020,1,1)
df['date'] = pd.date_range(firstdate, periods=df.shape[0]).tolist()
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

px.line(df, x = df.index, y = df.columns)



# fig = go.Figure([{
#     'x': df.index,
#     'y': df[col],
#     'name': col
# }  for col in df.columns])
# fig.show()

#  sns.set_style("darkgrid")
#sns.lineplot(data = df)
```

## [plotly express](https://plotly.com/python/plotly-express/)

```
px.line(df, x = df.index, y = df.columns)
```

Another plotly option is:

## [plotly graph_objects](https://plotly.com/python/graph-objects/)

```
fig = go.Figure([{
    'x': df.index,
    'y': df[col],
    'name': col
}  for col in df.columns])
fig.show()
```

## [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html)

```
sns.set_style("darkgrid")
sns.lineplot(data = df)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is now much easier than it was before in Plotly.

```
# IMPORTS
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px

# EXTRACT THE DATA
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Datum": [
            "1/1/2018 0:00",
            "1/1/2018 0:15",
            "1/1/2018 0:30",
            "1/1/2018 0:45",
            "1/1/2018 1:00",
            "1/1/2018 1:15",
            "1/1/2018 1:30",
            "1/1/2018 1:45 ",
        ],
        "Menge": [19.5, 19.0, 19.5, 19.5, 21, 19.5, 20, 23],
    }
)
```

### Plotly

```
px.line(x="Datum", y="Menge", data_frame=df, title="plotly example")
```

[image]

### Seaborn/Matplotlib

(The code is the same as the one in the top answer)

```
sns.lineplot(x="Datum", y="Menge", data=df)
plt.xticks(rotation=15)
plt.title('seaborn-matplotlib example')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Plotly solution last given here is wonderful.  Using the figure object it was also easy to set up a dictionary of labels for my data - since the data names given by the government are barely descriptive.  So the mere handful of lines of code:

```
columns = ['CPALTT01USM657N', 'UNRATE', 'TB3MS']
names = {'CPALTT01USM657N': 'Inflation Rate',
         'UNRATE': 'Unemployment Rate', 
         'TB3MS': '3 Mo. T-Bill Rate'}

fig = go.Figure([{
    'x': monthly_data['DATE'],
    'y': monthly_data[col],
    'name': names[col]
}  for col in columns])
fig.show(renderer='iframe')
```

Produced the following Plotly graph:
[image]